# extracting xml element one at a time

Tags: asp.net, xml

i am trying to extract xml element by name and below code does work but it does returns all 4 elements and below is my xml file.

what i want is to extract the frist element(`StripImages)[0]` ???

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xmlDoc.Load(menuUrl);
var stripImages = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("StripImage");

<Main>
<Author>
 .......
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
<Author>
 .......
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
<Author>
 .......
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
<Author>
 .......
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
 </Main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first use

```
stripImages[0]
```

or

```
stripImages.First()
```

** second one only works if you have the Linq-Xml extensions referenced and import `System.Linq`.

Based on your comment:

```
foreach(XmlNode image in stripImages)
{
      DoSomething(image);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to compare something like this `if (id == 1) { dosomething(image)}` ??? in your foreach loop

Comment: Sure, I mean you do whatever you need to in that foreach loop, just using image as the current iteration.  If you give an exact example of what you need, I can give you a better example

Answer (score 0):

If you can use linq to xml, try this

```
        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(menuUrl);
        var stripImages = xmlDoc.Descendants("StripImage").ToArray();
        var firstStringImage = stripImages[0];

        Console.WriteLine(stripImages [0]);
        Console.WriteLine(stripImages [1]);
        Console.WriteLine(stripImages [2]);
```

EDIT:

for input

```
<Main>
<Author>
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
<Author>
 <StripImage>false</StripImage>
</Author>
<Author>
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
<Author>
 <StripImage>true</StripImage>
</Author>
 </Main>
```

Outputs

```
<StripImage>true</StripImage>
<StripImage>false</StripImage>
<StripImage>true</StripImage>
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Abu you should have `using System.Xml.Linq;` and `using System.Linq;`

Comment: oops.. i have added those namespace but i get new error: `  stripImages[1] Out of bounds array index System.Xml.Linq.XElement
`

Comment: i should be able to do something like this rite? `stripImages[0]` or `stripImages[1]` ...

Comment: throwing me error with `stripImages[1] Out of bounds array index System.Xml.Linq.XElement`

Comment: @Abu check out the edit. If it still doesn't work then something is wrong with `menuUrl` .